# How to append empty row after each customers in a python dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
        df1:
        Customer         Manager           Time Period      Amount
        Samsung     Rosalie             90D     46726190
        Samsung     Rosalie             18M     46726190
        Samsung     Rosalie             18M     46726190
        Samsung     Rosalie             18M     46726190
        Samsung     Rosalie             30D     46726190
        Samsung     Rosalie             30D     46726190
        Apple       Abir                24M     359233179
        Apple       Abir                30D     359233179
        Apple       Abir                30D     25000000
        Nokia       Abir                90D     571711209
        Nokia       Abir                24M     571711209
        Nokia       Abir                24M     -284461
        Nokia       Abir                1M      571711209
        Nokia       Abir                1M      49715539
        Google      Michael             90D     49850165
        Google      Michael             12M     49850165
        Google      Michael             12M     49850165
        Google      Michael             12M     33048028
        Google      Michael             12M     49850165
        Google      Michael             12M     33048028
        Blackberry  Zec             90D     27975518
        Blackberry  Zec             18M     27975518
        Blackberry  Zec             30D     27975518
        Blackberry  Zec             30D     27975518
    
    Expected Output
    
    df1:
    Customer         Manager    Time Period Amount
    Samsung     Rosalie Navarrete   90D     46726190
    Samsung     Rosalie Navarrete   18M     46726190
    Samsung     Rosalie Navarrete   18M     46726190
    Samsung     Rosalie Navarrete   18M     46726190
    Samsung     Rosalie Navarrete   30D     46726190
    Samsung     Rosalie Navarrete   30D     46726190
    
    Apple       Abir Paul           24M     359233179
    Apple       Abir Paul           30D     359233179
    Apple       Abir Paul           30D     25000000
    
    Nokia       Abir Paul           90D     571711209
    Nokia       Abir Paul           24M     571711209
    Nokia       Abir Paul           24M     -284461
    Nokia       Abir Paul           1M      571711209
    Nokia       Abir Paul           1M      49715539
    
    Google      MichaelZec          90D     49850165
    Google      MichaelZec          12M     49850165
    Google      MichaelZec          12M     49850165
    Google      MichaelZec          12M     33048028
    Google      MichaelZec          12M     49850165
    Google      MichaelZec          12M     33048028


How to add a blank row after each of the customer in dataframe, as shown in expected output?
```

Tried Code:

for index, row in df.iterrrows():
if df.loc[index,'Customer Code'] != df.loc[index+1,'Customer Code'] and not(pd.isna(df.iloc[index,'Customer Code'])) and not(pd.isna(df.iloc[index+1,'Type']))
df.loc[index+1] = pd.Series([np.nan,np.nan, np.nan, np.nan])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a dictionary of Customer dfs. Iterate keys filter with [.query()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) and append a NaN row. Append Customer df to dfs empty list. Finally concat list of dfs, fillna, reset index and drop last row.

```
df_mapping = {x: pd.DataFrame for x in df["Customer"].unique().tolist()}

dfs = []
for key in df_mapping.keys():
    df_mapping[key] = df.query("Customer.eq(@key)").append(pd.Series(dtype="object"), ignore_index=True)
    dfs.append(df_mapping[key])

final_df = pd.concat(dfs).fillna("").reset_index(drop=True).iloc[:-1, :]
print(final_df)

      Customer  Manager Time Period       Amount
0      Samsung  Rosalie         90D   46726190.0
1      Samsung  Rosalie         18M   46726190.0
2      Samsung  Rosalie         18M   46726190.0
3      Samsung  Rosalie         18M   46726190.0
4      Samsung  Rosalie         30D   46726190.0
5      Samsung  Rosalie         30D   46726190.0
6                                               
7        Apple     Abir         24M  359233179.0
8        Apple     Abir         30D  359233179.0
9        Apple     Abir         30D   25000000.0
10                                              
11       Nokia     Abir         90D  571711209.0
12       Nokia     Abir         24M  571711209.0
13       Nokia     Abir         24M    -284461.0
14       Nokia     Abir          1M  571711209.0
15       Nokia     Abir          1M   49715539.0
16                                              
17      Google  Michael         90D   49850165.0
18      Google  Michael         12M   49850165.0
19      Google  Michael         12M   49850165.0
20      Google  Michael         12M   33048028.0
21      Google  Michael         12M   49850165.0
22      Google  Michael         12M   33048028.0
23                                              
24  Blackberry      Zec         90D   27975518.0
25  Blackberry      Zec         18M   27975518.0
26  Blackberry      Zec         30D   27975518.0
27  Blackberry      Zec         30D   27975518.0
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have range index

```
    Customer    Manager Time    Period      Amount
0   Samsung     Rosalie 90D     46726190    NaN
1   Samsung     Rosalie 18M     46726190    NaN
2   Samsung     Rosalie 18M     46726190    NaN
3   Samsung     Rosalie 18M     46726190    NaN
4   Samsung     Rosalie 30D     46726190    NaN
5   Samsung     Rosalie 30D     46726190    NaN
6   Apple       Abir    24M    359233179    NaN
7   Apple       Abir    30D    359233179    NaN
```

1. get index of groups tail(1) and + 0.5, declare `new_idx`
2. add `new_idx` to `df1.index`
3. reindex by union of index (make NaN rows)
4. finally reset_index

```
new_idx = df1.groupby('Customer').tail(1).index + 0.5
df1.reindex(index=df1.index.union(new_idx)).reset_index(drop=True)
```